# Unable to use AbstractProcessor in IDEs

Tags: java, intellij-idea, netbeans, annotation-processing

**Motivation:**

In our code we have a few places where some methods are run by their name. There are some big `if-else-if` blocks with each function name and call of the corresponding method (I use the term function to describe just names, for example function `X01` might correspond to method `SomeClass.functionX01`). I've been looking into ways to improve that

**Goal:**

Write just methods that are annotated with some custom annotation, removing the need to update or even include `if-else-if` blocks in order to run specific function. Have access to any generated code if any code is generated.

**What I did:**

I've created first prove of concept using runtime annotations and it proved successful, but slower then `if-else-if`. Next attempt was with source annotation

I've followed [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder) link for an example, however it did not seam to run in IntelliJ. What I wanted is to have - in this case `PersonBuilder` class generated, instead there was none. In some cases an error was raised `Error:java: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor: Provider BuilderProcessor not found`

After some Googling and failing to find anything I've turned to book (Core Java, Volume II - Advanced Features - 9th Edition, Polish translation) and there was reccomended to run the following commands:

```
javac [AbstractProcessor implementation]
javac -processor [Compiled Processor] [other source files to compile]
```

This worked, however is unsatisfactory as it needs to happen inside IDE (NetBeans and IntelliJ to be specific) automatically during build. Code does not need to be generated on the fly, but programmer must have access to it after build (as in - be able to call methods of generated classes)

**Question:**

How to have and use generated code used in NetBeans and IntelliJ without the need of using external tools? Is it possible, or using reflection, runtime annotations or external tools is the only way?

**Additional info (just in case):**

Language level: Java 1.8

JVM versions: 12 and 13

IDEs: NetBeans and IntelliJ

Comment: Can't you use lambdas to achieve what you describe in the "Motivation" section at the start of the question? If not, why not? And if you can, why do you prefer to go down a different path (i.e using annotations)? My apologies if I'm completely misunderstanding your issue.

Comment: I have not considered lambdas because I don't see the use for them. The ultimate goal is to remove that if, or at least have it generated. Lambdas don't provide that mechanism as far as I know, but if you know how to do such a thing please share.

Comment: OK. I think it would be helpful if you updated your question to show a sample of your existing code with those _if-else-if..._ statements, and also how your "function name" variable is being set (since that determines which method to call, right?).

Comment: The reason why I didn't include those if-else-if is that they themselves are very trivial - just `[else] if(todo.equals("SomeName")) functionSomeName(params)` over and over.

As for how function name is set - that unfortunately comes from an API call. Client on the other side of the ethernet cable runs webmethod say `runFunction("F01")` and functionF01 is called. If that happened inside the program, then polymorphism would probably solve it.